# Start 10 sec countdown When i click Download Button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found an example to do this function but I want to edit it to start when i click the button, not on document load.

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/rATW7/506/

```
var downloadButton = document.getElementById("download");
var counter = 10;
var newElement = document.createElement("p");
newElement.innerHTML = "You can download the file in 10 seconds.";
var id;
downloadButton.parentNode.replaceChild(newElement, downloadButton);
id = setInterval(function() {
    counter--;
    if(counter < 0) {
        newElement.parentNode.replaceChild(downloadButton, newElement);
        clearInterval(id);
    } else {
        newElement.innerHTML = "You can download the file in " + counter.toString() + " seconds.";
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Stop asking people to write code for you. Simply read up on jQuery on click events to achieve what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have on click event of jquery or in pure javascript you can attach function on onclick event.

```
<button id="btn">click</button>

function startDownload(){
  this.style.display = 'none';
  id = setInterval(function () {
    counter--;
    if (counter < 0) {
        newElement.parentNode.replaceChild(downloadButton, newElement);
        clearInterval(id);
    } else {
        newElement.innerHTML = +counter.toString() + " second.";
    }
}, 1000);
};

 var clickbtn= document.getElementById("btn");
 clickbtn.onclick=startDownload;
```

[**Fiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rATW7/508/)

Comment: Thanks , i want to remove "you can download file in .." i just need the counter , also please hide the button when clicked, and start 10 sec, then hide "10 sec" and show "download file button" , like 4shared download system.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you've the download button in your `HTML` which you're replacing with the warning paragraph, and after the countdown you're again replacing the paragraph with download button.

Looks like you can avoid unnecessary `DOM` manipulation by having the paragraph in `html` and replacing it with the download button after countdown.

HTML

```
<p id='message'>You can download the file in<span id='count'> 10</span> seconds.</p
<button id='start'>Click to start</button
```

Script

```
var message = document.getElementById("message");
var startBtn = document.getElementById("start");
var count = document.getElementById("count");
var timer;
var counter = 10;
var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
downloadLink.href = "downloadFile.zip";
downloadLink.className += "button";
downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download the file…";
function startDownload() {
 this.style.display = 'none';
 timer = setInterval(function () {
    counter--;
    if (counter < 0) {
        message.style.display = 'none';
        startBtn.parentNode.appendChild(downloadLink);
        clearInterval(timer);
    } else {
        count.innerHTML = " "+counter.toString();
    }
 }, 1000);
};
startBtn.onclick = startDownload;
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/rATW7/509/)